# Consider the positive random variable X with finite first moment

Tags: probability, statistics

Let we consider the positive random variable $X$ with finite first moment, how can we prove that: 
$$E \sqrt{X} \leq \sqrt{EX}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use Jensen Inequality to prove the inequality:
$$
\mathbb{E}(f(X))\geq f(\mathbb{E}(X))
$$
if $f$ is convex. Now because $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is concave you have:
$$
\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X}))\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X)}
$$

Comment: In the present case, Cauchy-Schwartz is enough.

Comment: It is also true that $\mathbb{E}(X^2)\geq (\mathbb{E}(X))^2.
$

Comment: Sorry: Schwarz with no t.